xrandr: Blank screen with flickering cursor
I have an HP laptop of the 15s series with AMD Ryzen™ 3 3250U with Radeon™ Graphics × 4. According to the specs of the processor, it can support a max resolution of 3840x2160 - 60 Hz. I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The current settings in ubuntu only let me use the resolution upto 1366x768.
I want to increase this resolution; upon researching I found this solution on askubuntu.com which kinda worked, it added the new resolution in the resolution dropdown in display settings, but when I selected the new resolution and applied the changes, the screen just went blank and the cursor started flickering. I waited for a few minutes but the state was still the same. I had to manually turn off the system via the power button and restart it. Any help regarding how to fix this blank screen with a flickering cursor would be appreciated!
Note:

the display in my case if eDP and not VGA-0
I tried to set a custom resolution of 1680x1050 with 60 hz
Here is the output of the xrandr command from my terminal:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
  1366x768      60.06*+  40.04  
  1280x720      60.06  
  1024x768      60.06  
  800x600       60.06  
  640x480       60.06  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Thank you

Please edit the question and add this info and any other relevant info. Please do not use comments to add info it may never be seen.

@David Hey, i've made the relevant changes as you asked to
